# Python: remove unicode from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I will use a simple dataframe as an example:

```
data = {'A': ['公司\u3000', 'aaaa\uf505'], 'B': ['1', '2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)


       A   B
0  公司　  1
1  aaaa   2
```

I want to remove unicode like '\u3000', '\uf505' from column A, however, there are more unicodes in it that I may not know. So it's not very ideal to use remove method for me. Some rows has Mandarin characters and I have to keep them.

It also did not work when I tried to split '\'

```
df=df[~df['A'].str.contains(r'\\')]
```

My expected result:

```
      A   B
0  公司　 1
1  aaaa   2
```

Comment: *they are all Unicode characters*, so you need to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F\u4E00-\u9FFF]+', '', regex=True)
```

df

```
    A       B
0   公司  1
1   aaaa    2
```

This code removes Unicode characters while preserving chinese characters(漢字).

Comment: It only preserves some hanzi. Ideographs outside that range will be stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to remove all unicode characters from column A in your DataFrame. Here's how you can do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'A': ['bbbb\u3000', 'aaaa\uf505'], 'B': ['1', '2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to remove unicode characters from a string
def remove_unicode(text):
    return re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', text)

# Apply the function to column A
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(remove_unicode)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      A  B
0  bbbb  1
1  aaaa  2
```

This code will remove all unicode characters from column A while leaving other characters intact.

Comment: Hi! It will also remove some Mandarin characters in some rows, but I have to keep them. I will edit my qustion again.